# How many levels for administration divide?

Tags: administrative-boundaries

Excuse my ignorance, I just want to know how many levels for boundaries divide in a global level?

What's Admin 4 btw?

Comment: What dataset is this question about? OpenStreetMap? Also please remove the `global-mapper` tag if you are not using the "Global Mapper geographic information system (GIS) software package developed by Blue Marble Geographics".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to go to **Gu** (District) or Submunicipal level divisions **Eup** (Town) for South Korea.

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_South_Korea

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_administrative_divisions_by_country

Admin 4 is a Administrative 4 Level Boundary.  United States is structured as follows: Admin 0 - Nation, Admin 1 States along with Federal District (DC), Admin 2 - Counties & Independent Cities, etc

Sometimes these are straight forward, but sometimes people, governments, and different organizations may disagree on the amount, the names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a single rule for administrative units globally, because of the history of the country and the differences in terms of population density, size and governance. In Europe, the standard divisions are the NUTS and there are three levels. But as you can see on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) , not all countries have the three levels. Furthermore, the smallest country levels are sometimes smaller than NUTS 3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. cuz I got confused when negotiating price on purchasing boundaries data. The company replied me with a narrow down option on a 50 bugs metadata sample on "Admin 4". Unfortunately, I don't really understand this tune.

Comment: The provided sample is targeted to South Korea btw.